# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ diverges absolutely and converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, $0<a<b<2\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am having trouble with this. I think I have to do the summation by parts formula, and I believe I proved that it converges uniformly, but I don't know how to prove that it diverges uniformly for all $x$.

Thank you!

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{e^{inx}}{n}$ converges because $\sum_{n\le N} e^{inx}$ is bounded and $\frac1n-\frac1{n+1} = O(\frac1{n^2})$. If $\sum_{n}\frac{|\cos(nx)|}{n}$ converges then so does $\sum_{n}\frac{\cos(nx)^2}{n}$.

Comment: @reuns why can't $\sum_n \frac{\cos^2(nx)}{n}$ converge?

Comment: @D.R. Because $\sum_n \frac{\cos^2(nx)}{n}$ is a linear combination of $\sum_n \frac{e^{inkx}}{n}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you be a little bit more explicit in your solution? What do you mean it's a linear combination? Could you show how?

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I've ever encountered the phrase "diverges uniformly" before. One says it does not converge uniformly. "Uniform" is not a fitting adjective for "divergence."

As a function of $x,$ the sum of any finite number of terms of this series is a continuous function since it's a sum of finitely many continuous functions. If a sequence of continuous functions coverges uniformly, then the limit is continuous. Every continuous function on a closed bounded interval such as $[0,2\pi]$ is bounded. But when $x=0$ or $x=2\pi,$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(nx)/n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n = +\infty.$ So this cannot converge uniformly.